# Vue cli 3 conflicts with apollo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, apollo

I am following the tutorial, and I have stumbled over some problems. When I imported Apollo and Apollo boost console becomes full of errors

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"; //import apollo-boost
import VueApollo from "vue-apollo"; // import vue-apollo

Vue.use(VueApollo); // use apollo

// Setup ApolloClient
const defaultClient = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
});

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({ defaultClient }); // implementing provider

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({ // vue constructor
    provide: apolloProvider.provide(), // provide
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Error in the console `"error in ../node_modules/graphql/index.mjs"`

I found this solution `https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1637` but I have no idea how implement this. They paste some code to the `vue.config.js`, but instead, I have `babel.config.js`, are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the GitHub link you mentioned, the solution is to configure Webpack via the `vue.config.js`, which is an *optional* file in a Vue CLI project. That file is omitted by default, so you would have to create the file if it doesn't exist.

From the Vue CLI [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js):

> `vue.config.js` is an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by `@vue/cli-service` if it's present in your project root (next to `package.json`). You can also use the `vue` field in `package.json`, but do note in that case you will be limited to JSON-compatible values only.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  apolloProvider,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```